# PHP session value empty?

Tags: php, session

I set using PHP value when user is logged like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = 'kikiriki';
```

Later in my code i want to retreive `$_SESSION['login']` using this code:

```
session_start();
echo 'comment is from user logged: '+print_r($_SESSION['login']);
```

and i get this:

```
kikiriki0
```

i want to retrieve using this code but i get only `0`:

```
session_start();
echo 'comment is from user logged: '+echo($_SESSION['login']);
```

And result is 0...why result is not kikiriki?

Comment: Are you staring the session more than once during a single request?

Comment: Time to check with `var_dump`.

Comment: Your echoing the value returned by `echo()` - change `user logged: '.$_SESSION['login'];`

Comment: try session_start();
echo 'comment is from user logged: '.$_SESSION['login'];

Comment: No , only once when user is logged....if i run print_r i get correct value every time...but i need to use echo($_SESSION['login']); therefore i get always 0

Comment: You're getting 0 because you are concatenating the string incorrectly. You're using `+` instead of `.`, When you use `+` all strings are interpreted as 0 unless they start with an integer

Comment: Just change the + for a .

Comment: Thanks i forget that + uses javascipt PHP uses . thanks

Comment: this is definitely a typo question. To concatenate in php, use `.` not `+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change...

```
echo 'comment is from user logged: '+echo($_SESSION['login']);
```

to

```
echo 'comment is from user logged: '.$_SESSION['login'];
```

Your trying to add (not concatenate) the items.

Comment: aaa see the point i use + not . (+ uses javascript PHP uses . so there was problem)..i was working login system in client side using javascript and in server side using PHP and mistype...now is working fine thanks

Comment: I tend to try and add strings in Javascript using `.` and wonder why it doesn't work!

Comment: @John Glad to hear it's workign for you. If this answer fixed your issue, you should accept it!

Answer (score -1):

You should do like this:

echo 'comment is from user logged: '.$_SESSION['login'];

*// print -> comment is from user logged: kikiriki*

or

echo $_SESSION['login'];

*//Print -> kikiriki*

Comment: This should be accepted as well, not sure what's wrong with this answer.